# How to get a very long decimal digit by dividing a irrational number with another number in Python?

Tags: python, numbers

```
import math
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 10000
phi = str(Decimal(1+math.sqrt(5))/Decimal (2) )
print(phi)
print(len(phi))

#output >> phi - 1.6180339887498949025257388711906969547271728515625
#output >> len(phi) - 51
```

I wanted to get a 1000 digits long number but in Python, the limit seems to be at 51. So how can I do to get a very long digit in Python?

Answer (score 2):

The `math` module works with native binary floating-point arithmetic.  So the crucial

```
1+math.sqrt(5)
```

part has nothing to do with the decimal precision you set.  That part is done entirely in native binary floating-point.

To keep the output to reasonable length, let's try for 80 significant decimal digits instead.  So

```
getcontext().prec = 80
```

and then

```
phi = str((1 + Decimal(5).sqrt()) / 2)
```

instead.  Clear?  Now the `sqrt` method *of* a decimal object is being used instead, and that will respect the decimal precision you set.  You can force `1` and `2` to `Decimal` too but there's no real need to - they'll be converted automatically to `Decimal` because their other operand is `Decimal`.  Output from the above:

```
1.6180339887498948482045868343656381177203091798057628621354486227052604628189024
81
```